# CVS status for files that are not Up-to-date

Tags: cvs, status

cvs -q status gives me an output like this:-

===================================================================

File: file1.xml        Status: Up-to-date

Working revision:    1.1

Repository revision: 1.1     /cvs/path/file1.xml,v

Commit Identifier:   pmLlaTWaaXUFOvQw

Sticky Tag:          (none)

Sticky Date:         (none)

Sticky Options:      (none)

===================================================================

File: file2.xml         Status: Up-to-date

Working revision:    1.1

Repository revision: 1.1     /cvs/path/file2.xml,v

Commit Identifier:   qnJg8rCyPbtNOvQw

Sticky Tag:          (none)

Sticky Date:         (none)

Sticky Options:      (none)

I would like an output as above but for all files that have a status that is not "Up-to-date".
I currently use this command that I found and adapted for statues I do want:-

cvs -q status|awk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=1 a=9 s='(Locally Modified)|(Needs Patch)|(Needs Checkout)|(Locally Modified)'

but this is limited to me specifying all the statues, but what I really want is to say !="Up-to-date".
Any ideas how I could achieve this?.
Thanks.
Ian.